# Live audio stream valid HTTP resource

Tags: php, streaming, mp3, shoutcast

Shoutcast servers not generate valid HTTP resource. Our mobile player link (Android) requires a valid HTTP resource. How can i use php script for shoutcast stream? This script provide valid http resource? Any one knows?

```
<?php

$track = "shoutcaststream.mp3";

if (file_exists($track)) {
    header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($track));
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="shoutcaststream.mp3"');
    header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    readfile($track);
    exit;
} else {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
    echo "no file";
}
```

**Update 2**

Everything now fine asper "Brad" instructions. We use set_time_limit(0) But still my stream closed after 3 mins to 5 mins? How to fix? Kindly help me.. :)

Comment: i mean shoutcast mp3 output dont have "Content-Type"

Comment: You ask if it's a valid **HTTP resource** and then you say that it means that it has `Content-Type`, while in your code you have `header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");`. Too vague ...

Comment: Hey guys, there is nothing wrong with his question.  The problem he is having is a well-known issue when working with SHOUTcast streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you have is valid.

The invalid part about SHOUTcast streams is that they return `ICY 200 OK` instead of `HTTP/1.0 200 OK` in their responses.  If you wish to change your script to proxy the SHOUTcast request,  you will likely need to connect to your SHOUTcast server via a normal TCP connection (see [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)), and send the raw request data.

Once you have a connection and are receiving data, echo this data out to your client.

Also note that you will want to call `set_time_limit(0)` so that your script doesn't time out in 30 seconds or so.  Also make sure to not send a `Content-Length` header, and set your response to be `HTTP/1.0` so that you don't have to send the data as chunked.  (Chunked encoding playback only works on Android 2.3 or later.)

Finally, if you find that hacking something in place with PHP is too much of a hassle, I have a [stream hosting service available for testing](http://audiopump.co/preview.php) that does exactly what you are asking, which works fine for the built-in audio player on Android.

Comment: Everything now fine. We use set_time_limit(0) But still my stream closed after 3 mins to 5 mins? How to fix? Kindly help me.. :)

Comment: @Joshua, You probably have something killing off the PHP process.  Is this your server?  Many hosts will kill PHP processes regularly.  With no interference, the process can run indefinitely.  Also check for memory leaks.